# Incredibly slow connection to EC2 instance after moving to another region

Tags: amazon-ec2

I just moved my instance from Frankfurt to N. Virginia, and now I'm getting really slow loading times for my website. The DOM loads quickly, but then I wait over 40 seconds for a 500kb image. This shouldn't be happening, am I missing a config somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Where in the world are you located?

All else being equal (i.e., barring any changes to your network configuration or VPC settings), if you're located in Europe, it makes little sense to host your website on a U.S. server because traffic has to travel through undersea cables in the Atlantic. The latency between the two locations will increase noticeably.

For someone located in the U.S., your website should now load faster because they are physically closer to the server.

You should always pick a server location nearest to your main audience. If most of your website visitors are in Europe, best stick with the Frankfurt location, or pick a different one in Europe.

Comment: How could one measure the loading time from different locations?

Comment: Increased latency wouldn't be giving 40-second delays.  Even if the server were located on the Moon, latency would only give maybe ten seconds of loading delay.